# convert int to wstring

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I want to convert an integer value (int) to std::wstring. What is the best way to do this? I'm developing for windows phone so I would rather avoid using external libraries (such as boost::lexical_cast). I'm looking for something simple, preferably one line of code that just assigns the int to the wstring.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Are you looking for [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring)

```
std::wstring to_wstring( int value );   (since C++11)
```

> Converts a signed decimal integer to a wide string with the same content as what std::swprintf(buf, sz, L"%d", value) would produce for sufficiently large buf.

Comment: @WhozCraig me neither, was trying to find the `wstring` page

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. The answer couldn't be better. I didn't even know this was available. Nothing showed up when I googled my question.

Comment: no wonder the coding world is so messed up, half implemented standards *shakes head in disgust at the IT industry*

Answer (score 3):

```
    size_t myInteger = 10;
    std::wostringstream myStringStream;
    myStringStream<< L"myText" << myInteger;
    std::wstring concatenatedStr = myStringStream.str();
```

Conacatenating number to wstring.

In old C++ 98 Visual Studio 2010.